# Bridging header not found in header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I have this annoying error that stops me from developing some features in my app. 
Here is the thing:

- I developed a swift/objc project
- The bridging header works every where in my project
- I import it in .m files and this works !

Now I have this file EventCell.h:

- I import the bridging header in it : no problem

From another file CalendarView.h:

- I import EventCell.h in it

And boom [image]

I can't get this issue ! Please help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot import the bridging header into a .h file. You should use forward declarations if you need access to a Swift class.

Use `@class MyClassName, or @protocol MyProtocolName`

Comment: Perfect, I actually did not know forward declarations, you learnt me something ! Thank you